# Saber si el Update fue Exitoso Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

hay forma de saber si el update que ejecuto mediante una instrucción Sql a una Tabla Access fue exitoso?
Para Sql Server lo haría así:

```
update my_tabla set nombre="ariel" where id=1
Select @@error as errorinsert, @@rowcount as cambios , @@spid aS id_conexion
```

y el select me retorna si hubo errores y cuantos registros se modificaron.
Esto en access no funciona, existe alguna forma?

Comment: Cuando ejecutas una consulta de actualización en Access, salta un aviso diciendo que vas a modificar X registros. ¿Te refieres a eso?

Comment: Claro, pero lo necesito en una variable para poder evaluarla desde mi sistema realizado en VFP usando una BD access

Comment: La única manera que conozco sería usando VBA, no sé si eso te podría ayudar.